# using `for file in` to select multiple extension names then get the basename of "file" then concatenate an extension name

Tags: shell, for

I am trying to practice my unix skills, I just learned how to use `for file in *.jpg;` what it does is select all files with `.jpg` in the working directory, but I do not want to stop there and I do not want to run my bash script twice

So here is the scenario, I got these files, and I wish is select each one of them, then replace the extension name to another and I hope the process will be something like `basename` + ".done" so `test1.jpg` becomes `test1.done`

```
test1.jpg
test2.jpeg
test3.txt
test4.dummy
```

Now, what I want is to somehow, put these extension names `.jpg,.jpeg,.txt,.dummy` in an array, then use that in `for` loop something like `for file in *{.jpg,.jpeg,.txt,.dummy}; do`, but I tried it and it does not work, the shell seems to not allow arrays in for loop?

can somebody help me and give me an example how to solve this? thanks!

**UPDATE**

so, I learned that using `for file in *.{jpg,jpeg,test}` will solve my problem, but sometimes it fails, specially when there's no file with an extension declared in the array

Example:

```
test1.jpg
test2.jpeg
test3.test
test4.dummy
```

Using a bash like:

```
for file in *.{jpg,jpeg,test,avi}; do size=$(stat -c '%s' "$file"); echo $file filesize is: $size; done
```

will end up ugly:

```
test1.jpg filesize is: 2
test2.jpeg filesize is: 0
test3.test filesize is: 0
stat: cannot stat `*.avi': No such file or directory
*.avi filesize is:
```

the last 2 lines above is unnecessary, I wish there is something like a `break` where if `for` cannot find any `avi` then stop the `do`

Is this possible?

Comment: 1 - try *.{jpg,jpeg,txt,dummy} -- 2 - in your sample, you'll generate test1.done from test.jpg and test1.done from test1.jpeg.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us your desired output. I can't understand if you want to have the extensions in an array or if you just want to change the extension of all files to `.done`.

Comment: @terdon it looks like the OP means _list_ where they've written _array_. They them go on to say they've tried `*{.jpg,.jpeg,.txt,.dummy}` so I wonder if it's an older shell that doesn't understand the `{x,y,z}` type construct.

Comment: @roaima perhaps, this is CentOS after all. Still, we can't provide an answer unless the question is clarified. The simple answer of course is that brace expansion is not needed at all: `for f in *jpg *jpeg *txt *dummy; do...`. For more details, we need to understand exactly what the OP is attempting.

Comment: @Archemar thank you very much to your reply guys, I already updated my question. :)

Comment: @roaima I updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `bash`, you can set the `nullglob` option:

```
  nullglob
    If set, bash allows patterns which match no  files  (see
    Pathname  Expansion  above)  to expand to a null string,
    rather than themselves.
```

To illustrate:

```
$ ls
test1.dummy  test1.jpeg  test1.jpg  test1.test
$ shopt nullglob
nullglob        off
$ for file in *.{jpg,jpeg,test,avi}; do 
    echo "$file size is $(stat -c '%s' "$file")"; 
  done
test1.jpg size is 0
test1.jpeg size is 0
test1.test size is 0
stat: cannot stat ‘*.avi’: No such file or directory
*.avi size is
```

And if we activate `nullglob`:

```
$ shopt -s nullglob 
$ shopt nullglob ## just to demonstrate that it is on
nullglob        on
$ for file in *.{jpg,jpeg,test,avi}; do      
    echo "$file size is $(stat -c '%s' "$file")"
 done
test1.jpg size is 0
test1.jpeg size is 0
test1.test size is 0
```

Alternatively, you could just make sure that the file exists (I am also using this example top demonstrate that brace expansion is not needed here):

```
$ for file in *jpg *jpeg *test *avi; do
    [ -e "$file" ] &&  echo "$file size is $(stat -c '%s' "$file")" 
  done
test1.jpg size is 0
test1.jpeg size is 0
test1.test size is 0
```